# Prevent text selection on input on taphold

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a HTML5 mobile website.  I have some `<input>` boxes where the desired behavior is to toggle a class on taphold event while still allowing text input.  I use:

```
$('input').bind('taphold', strikeHandler);
```

This works great, except that when I taphold on my Android device the Copy/Paste options comes up and this is very disruptive.  I can avoid this by adding the CSS:

```
input { -webkit-user-select: none !important; }
```

However, this prevents me from being able to edit the text in the input box.

How can I prevent the Copy/Paste behavior in Android while still allowing the input to be editable?